# OLS regression storing problem: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have a problem with this for loop in python. I'm trying to iterate the OLS command in a cross-section data where I'have multiple id observed during the same period. I want to do a regression for each id of each year, of each month.

When i try to run singurlarly the commands they works but in the loop the output is always the same:**zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity**. I have no idea where is the problem in the for loop. The problem is in the last 8 rows (i have uploaded the other only to make sense to them).
Thanks in advance for your support.

````
import pandas as pd\\
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from datetime import datetime as dt
from sklearn import linear_model as lm
import numpy as np
data=pd.DataFrame()
data=pd.read_excel('gggg.xlsx', sheet_name='Foglio1')
data['Data']=pd.to_datetime(data['Data'])
data["year"]=data['Data'].dt.year
data["month"]=data['Data'].dt.month

sl=pd.wide_to_long(data, ['R','RM','V','MktCap'], i="Data", j="group_id")


sl["month1"]=sl["month"].shift(-1)
sl['monthindicator'] = np.where(sl['month']!=sl['month1'], 1, 0)
sl["year1"]=sl["year"].shift(-1)
sl['yearindicator'] = np.where(sl['year']!=sl['year1'], 1, 0)


sl['AdjVol']=sl['V']/sl['MktCap']
sl['id']=sl.index.get_level_values('group_id')

for i in range(1,11): 
    for y in range(2012,2020):
        for m in range(1,13):
            Y=sl.loc[(sl['id']==i) & (sl["year"]==y) & (sl["month"]==m), "R"]
            X=sl.loc[(sl['id']==i) & (sl["year"]==y) & (sl["month"]==m), "RM"]
            result = sm.OLS(Y, sm.add_constant(X))
            result=result.fit()
            sl["prediction"] = result.predict()  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

it usually happens when there is missing value in dataset, you better try df.dropna(how='all') and test it